# Keep external website always inside iframe

Tags: iframe

I have a website (made with CakePHP in case that matters) that in one of its pages loads another website, a Wordpress blog to be more specific, inside an iframe. The URL loaded looks something like **myblogdomain.como/page_loaded.php**

When navigating the blog inside the iframe, "normal" links work fine (the read posts, see comments, access pages from the Wordpress navigation bar...). However, if the user chooses the option to "Edit My Profile", also inside the Wordpress blog, then the whole page inside the iframe disappears, showing the same page that loaded the iframe, but without the contents of the iframe.

I don't know if this happens because the "Edit My Profile" link points to a different folder (in this case **myblogdomain.com/wp-admin**) when the page I'm loading at the beginning inside the iframe it's directly in **myblogdomain.com**.

Is there any way to prevent that behavior and make that all navigation that happens within the iframe results in pages loaded inside the iframe?

**EDIT**

This is weird. What I explained above is what was happening last night. This morninf, without changing anything **at all**, when I click in any link of the blog I get this error message:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webadmin@kundenserver.de and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Just curious, is it in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I assume that it happens because 3rd party cookies in iframe are blocked by the browser. It happens most often in Internet Explorer, but basically it depends on the browser security settings. This could be fixed by setting P3P header to responses from your WordPress site. You can get some insights at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343.aspx#p3p_and_compact_policies or just google for "iframe cookies".

Comment: ok I'll do that, thank you. Assuming I solve this error, what about my original question? Is there a way to force the page to always load in the iframe?